# What format should the file for ConfigParser be?

Tags: python, configparser

I'm setting up my credentials for the library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/

Code for the relevant configparser on the project file [here](https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api/src/b3dc65abea626406ce9f406ac26f49888d74084f/amazonproduct/utils.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

I'm wondering, what format should the config file variables be? Should strings be inserted inside quotes? Should there be spaces between the variable name and the equal sign?

How does this look?

```
[Credentials]
access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
secret_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
associate_tag=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

> The configuration file consists of sections, led by a [section] header and followed by name: value entries, with continuations in the style of RFC 822 (see section 3.1.1, “LONG HEADER FIELDS”); name=value is also accepted. Note that leading whitespace is removed from values. The optional values can contain format strings which refer to other values in the same section, or values in a special DEFAULT section. Additional defaults can be provided on initialization and retrieval. Lines beginning with '#' or ';' are ignored and may be used to provide comments.
>
> Configuration files may include comments, prefixed by specific characters (# and ;). Comments may appear on their own in an otherwise empty line, or may be entered in lines holding values or section names. In the latter case, they need to be preceded by a whitespace character to be recognized as a comment. (For backwards compatibility, only ; starts an inline comment, while # does not.)
>
> On top of the core functionality, SafeConfigParser supports interpolation. This means values can contain format strings which refer to other values in the same section, or values in a special DEFAULT section. Additional defaults can be provided on initialization.
>
> For example:

```
[My Section]
foodir: %(dir)s/whatever
dir=frob
long: this value continues
   in the next line
```

You are pretty free in writing what ever you want in the settings file.

In your particular case you just need to copy & paste your keys and tag and ConfigParser should do the rest.